# CSS :: Reduce number with calc

Tags: html, css, numbers, css-tables, calc

That css script is working perfectly :

```
table
{
    counter-reset:rowNumber;
}

table tr
{
    counter-increment:rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before
{
    content:counter(rowNumber);
    min-width:1em;
    margin-right:0.5em;
}
```

But the thing is that I want to reduce -1 from rowNumber (or the other options reset the counter to -1)

I tried this :

```
content:counter(calc(rowNumber-1));
```

But seems like it's not working

Comment: I guess that's one option... table tr:not(:first-child) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

Comment: First time that I'm asking a question here and answering to myself :P

Comment: I solved it by :

    table tr:not(:first-child){counter-increment:rowNumber;}

But I'd be happy to hear different methods to solve that issue just for expending my css knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is use the adjacent sibling selector as in:

```
table tr + tr { /* attributes */ }
```

This is exactly the same as `table tr:not(:first-child)`, but I often use it for lists of anything.

```
ul li + li { margin-top: 1em }
```